# JAVA Signature Object - No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature

I want to sign a file i created using a pair of RSA keys I created using key tool and the following command:

`keytool -genkeypair -alias key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -validity 365 -keystore keystore.jks`

I want to initialize my Signature object so I tried this:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS,privateKeyPassword);
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
signature.initSign(privateKey);
```

But I got this exception:
`No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is `SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM` value?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that one `private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withDSA";`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `SHA1withDSA` with an RSA key.  Change signature algorithm to `SHA1withRSA` or generate a DSA key instea