# Decode SecretKey using Private Key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to load an AES SecretKey from a .pem file encrypted with a private key.

```
SecretKey loadAESKeyfromCertFile(String filename, PrivateKey prv) {
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, prv);
        byte[] b = new byte[256];
        in.read(b);
        byte[] keyb = cipher.doFinal(b);
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But i keep getting `java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl`

Comment: are you sure you don't mean the pem file has a private key and the pem file is encrypted with a password?

Comment: No, it's not encrypted with a password, its encrypted with the private key.  I have both the private and public keys, however, I need to retrieve the secret key. @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534827/java-signature-object-no-installed-provider-supports-this-key-sun-security-rs

Comment: Unfortunately no, it does not. Unlike the case you've pointed out, I have the 3 certificates and I just need to decrypt the pem file using the PrivateKey

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't make sense, and your comments don't provide much clarification. About all that we can deduce is that your are trying to initialize AES with an RSA private key, which of course will result in the exception you're seeing. Calling something a "pem" file is not enough information as all sort of incompatible crypto formats may be reasonably described as pem files, although offhand I can't think of any of them would hold an AES secretKey. Please add some clarifying information.